Keyclock SSO login with Jmeter
Facing SSO keyclock login issue with Jmeter. Can anyone help me to find the solution for this?
I have recorded the Keyclock SSO login scripts using HTTPs test script recorder. After this when I tried to run SSO login scripts using Jmeter it is throwing an error. As it having State_ID and Nounce as dynamic changing fields. Kindly help.
I can log in to the SSO, but it runs in a loop for 21 times before throwing an error
Error Screenshot

You need to correlate all dynamic values which are in your login sequence, to wit:

Identify dynamic values
Add suitable JMeter Post-Processors to extract the values from the previous response
Replace recorded hard-coded values with the JMeter Variables from step 2

Here is a small demo showing the process using Boundary Extractor


Also there is Auto Correlations Recorder Plugin for JMeter which can make the process easier and there is a free course on using the plugin: JMeter™ Autocorrelation Recorder

I can log in to the SSO, but it runs in a loop for 21 times before throwing an error

It looks like you're exceeding httpsampler.max_redirects limit which defaults to 20. If that high number of redirects is expected - you can raise the limit in user.properties file. If not - make sure that JMeter is sending the same requests as browser does. More information: Miscellaneous configuration and Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide
